# Shortcode for showing childpages

Tags: shortcode

I found this code snippet that shows childpages only.

It works great, doing exactly what i intend it to do.
I want to be able to place this around the site, but i cant place PHP inside the Rich-text editor. I want to convert it to a shortcode.

How do i convert this to a shortcode?

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
$parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
} else {
$parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
} ?>
<?php if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )): ?>
<div>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent" ); ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your theme's functions.php, it will add the shortcode `[child_pages]`:

```
function wpsc_child_pages($atts){
    global $wp_query;
    $html = '';
    if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
        $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
    } else {
        $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
    }
    $pages = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0");
    if( $pages ){
        $html .= "<div><ul>$pages</ul></div>";
    }
    return $html;        
}

add_shortcode('child_pages', 'wpsc_child_pages');
```

If you want to pass the function variables (e.g. `[child_pages parent=3]`) you would access that variable using the passed `$atts` argument.